# Selecting a list of n points within an specific radius in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a trajectory like this: We assume that each red star marker can broadcast its coordinate to the green circle markers which are located within a radius of 5 units from its own position.

[image]

How can I select a list of n red points for each green marker according to the above explanation. Thanks in advance.

This is my code, and I mentioned the coordinate of red points and green markers int it.

```
 %% Network Setup
anchor_num=1; % Number of anchor node
node_num=20;  % Total nodes
length1=70;   % Area length
anchor_x=0;   % Intial position of anchor x coordinate
anchor_y=0;   % Intial position of anchor y coordinate
anchormove=[];% Anchor trajectory
width=40;    % Area width
r = 30;     
A = zeros(0,2);
B = zeros(0,2);
C = zeros(0,2);
D = zeros(0,2);
north = [ 0 6.9];
east  = [ 6.9 0];
south = [ 0 -6.9];
west  = [-6.9 0];
order = 4;
for n = 1:order
  AA = [B ; north ; A ; east  ; A ; south ; C];
  BB = [A ; east  ; B ; north ; B ; west  ; D];
  CC = [D ; west  ; C ; south ; C ; east  ; A];
  DD = [C ; south ; D ; west  ; D ; north ; B];
  A = AA;
  B = BB;
  C = CC;
  D = DD;
end
% Plot network trajectory
%Mtrix A contains the coordinate of red markers.
A = [0 0; cumsum(A)]
p=plot(A(:,1),A(:,2))
title('Plot of Hilbert trajectory');
set(p,'Color','magenta ','LineWidth',2);
axis([0 100 0 100]);
hold on
% x and y are the coordinates of green markers
x=rand(1,100)*100;
y=rand(1,100)*100;
scatter(x,y)

anchormove(1,:)=A(:,1)'
anchormove(2,:)=A(:,2)'
idx=length(anchormove(1,:));
for i=1:idx-1
    % Plot the moving anchor node
    Ax=anchormove(1,i);
    Ay=anchormove(2,i);
    plot(Ax,Ay,'r*');
% Plot transmission range of the anchor node
    axis([0 100 0 100])
   % hold on
    pause(0.1)
    %hold off
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the statistics and machine learning toolbox you can do so by hand. To find all "red" points (from your code it seems they are contained in `A`) that are within range `R` from a specific green point (`x(i)`,`y(i)`), you can use

```
w = sqrt(sum((A - [x(i),y(i)]).^2,2)) <= R;
```

if you have Matlab >=R2016, otherwise

```
w = sqrt(sum((A - repmat([x(i),y(i)],size(A,1),1)).^2,2)) <= R;
```

Then, `w` is a logical array containing logical 1 for all anchor points within range `R` of `[x(i),y(i)]`. You can use logical indexing àla `A(w,:)` to retrieve them. For instance, `plot(A(w,1),A(w,2),'ks')` will plot them with a different marker.

If you need to do this for all your green points jointly, the code becomes

```
W = sqrt(sum(abs((reshape(A,size(A,1),1,2) - reshape([x;y]',1,length(x),2)).^2),3)) <= R;
```

on Matlab>=R2016. Now, `W` is a matrix where its rows are the red points and the columns are the green markers, containing a logical 1 if a pair is within radius `R` and 0 otherwise. You can for instance use `any(W,2)` to check whether the red points are within reach of any of the green markers.

For Matlab before R2016 you need to modify the above with some repmat magic:

```
W = sqrt(sum(abs((repmat(reshape(A,size(A,1),1,2),1,length(x),1) - repmat(reshape([x;y]',1,length(x),2),size(A,1),1,1)).^2),3)) <= R;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`rangesearch(X,Y,radius)`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/rangesearch.html). It returns a cell array where the  cells contain the indexes of the points `X` within a given `radius` for each point `Y`. Since the number of nearby points can vary for each `Y`, the number of indexes per cell may vary.

So in your case:

```
% turn the two x and y vectors into [x y] column format.
GreenPoints = [x;y].';
% get indexes of the points A for each Green point within 5 distance
idx = rangesearch(A,GreenPoints,5);
```

Or shorter:

```
idx = rangesearch(A,[x;y].',5);
```